# codeigniter ajax not setting sessions asynchronously

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, session

I am new to codeigniter ajax and i have a problem with sessions.My sessions are not being set and unset
asynchronously and i have to refresh the page just to see the changes.

view/header:

```
    <?php
if(!empty($product)){
$pid=$product[0]['product_id'];

}

?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.add_to_basket').find('img')){
$('.add_to_basket').click(function(){
        var message=$('#badgemessage');
    $('#msgcart').append(message);
    message.show('slow');
    var trigger=$(this);
    var param=trigger.attr("rel");
    var item=param.split("_");
            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?= base_url()."cart_c/myfunk/".$pid?>',

                data: { id: item[0], job: item[1] },
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data) {
                           console.log(data);       
                },
                error:function(){
                alert("error");
                }
            });
            return false;

});
    }
});



</script>
```

model/basket_model:

```
<?php
class Basket_model extends CI_Model{

    function activeButton($sess_id){
        $e=$this->session->userdata('basket');
        if(isset($e[$sess_id])){
        $id=0;
        $label="<img src='".base_url()."images/remove.png' />";
        }else{
            $id=1;
            $label="<img src='".base_url()."images/add.png' />";
        }
        $out="<a href='#' class='add_to_basket' rel='".$sess_id."_".$id."'>".$label."</a>";
        return $out;
    }

    function setItem($pide,$qty=1){
        $e=$this->session->userdata('basket');
        if(isset($e)){
    $e[$pide]['qty']=$qty;
    $this->session->set_userdata('basket',$e);
        }else{
            $arr=array($pide=>array('qty'=>$qty));
            $this->session->set_userdata('basket',$arr);
        }
}
    function removeItem($pide,$qty=null){
        $e= $this->session->userdata('basket');
        if($qty != null && $qty < $e[$pide]['qty']){
            $e[$pide]['qty']=($e[$pide]['qty']-$qty);
            $this->session->set_userdata('basket',$e);
        }else{
            $e[$pide]=null;
            unset($e[$pide]);
            $this->session->set_userdata('basket',$e);


        }

    }
}
?>
```

controller/cart_c:

```
<?php
class Cart_c extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('catalogue_model');
        $this->load->model('products_model');
        $this->load->model('basket_model');


    }

    function myfunk($id){
    if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['job'])) 
    $out=array();
    $pid=$_POST['id'];
    $job=$_POST['job'];
        if(!empty($id)){
            switch($job){
                case 0:
                $this->basket_model->removeItem($pid);
                $out['job']=1;
                break;

                case 1:
                $this->basket_model->setItem($pid);
                $out['job']=0;
                break;

            }
            echo json_encode($out);
        }


    }


}

?>
```

controller/products:

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('catalogue_model');
        $this->load->model('products_model');
        $this->load->model('basket_model');
    }

    function product($id){
    $kitties['cats']=$this->catalogue_model->get_categories();
    $data['product']=$this->products_model->get_product($id);
    $data['active_button']=$this->basket_model->activeButton($id);
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('sidebar',$kitties);
        $this->load->view('product',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}

?>
```

view/product:

```
<div class="contentwrap">
<div id="content_area">
<?php 

$e=$this->session->userdata('basket');
print_r($e);
if(!empty($product)){
    foreach($product as $p){
        ?>
        <h1><?=$p['product_name']?></h1>
        <div id="product_image">
        <img src="<?=base_url()?>/images/<?=$p['image']?>" width="400" height="300" />
        </div>
        <div id="product_desc">
        <?=$p['description']?>
        <br><br>
        <?=$active_button?>


        </div>
        <?php

    }

}else{
    echo "Product unavailable";
}?>




</div>
</div>
```

The problem is my $active_button in the product view is not changing asynchronously but the sessions are being set and unset
i can see items being pushed into and out of the session array when i refresh the page.When i hit the button my chrome console displays: object{job:0}

Comment: what do you get in your `print_r($e);` in your product view?

Comment: @CodeGodie i get printed out all the basket session...Array ( [10] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [qty] => 1 ) )    this means i have two products in the session

Comment: and you want to replace to the array, not add to it correct?

Comment: @CodeGodie look closely i have two functions setItem() and removeItem() being called via ajax respectively and they are working but my $active_button in the product view is not being updated to corresponding result

Comment: I see.. so after loading the product page, before clicking the button. how does the HTML look like for the element? is it something like this: `<a href='#' class='add_to_basket' rel='10_1'><img src='images/add.png' /></a>`

Comment: @CodeGodie yes it looks like that before clicking the button and after a click of a button the rel attribute changes to 10_0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after looking and studying youre code. you can implement what you want by retrieving the button again when making your AJAX call. The way to retrieve it is by calling that model again, then using jquery to replace the current button. Try the following:

Controller - Cart_c

```
function myfunk($id) {
    if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['job'])) {
        $out = array();

        $pid = $_POST['id'];
        $job = $_POST['job'];
        if (!empty($id)) {
            switch ($job) {
                case 0:
                    $this->basket_model->removeItem($pid);
                    $out['active_button'] = $this->basket_model->activeButton($pid);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    $this->basket_model->setItem($pid);
                     $out['active_button'] = $this->basket_model->activeButton($pid);
                    break;
            }
            echo json_encode($out);
        }
    }
}
```

JS in header view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function add_to_basket($this) {
            var param = $this.attr("rel");
            var item = param.split("_");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?= base_url() . "cart_c/myfunk/" . $pid ?>',
                data: {id: item[0], job: item[1]},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $this.replaceWith(data.active_button);
                    $('.add_to_basket').click(function() {
                        add_to_basket($(this));
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

        $('.add_to_basket').click(function() {
            add_to_basket($(this));
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: omg dude you are awsome...thank you very much...i've been struggling for two days trying to make it work

Comment: no problem man.. I was just a little confused initially on what your end result was suppose to be like.. I think you were getting confused thinking that the front-end would be updated by itself. Anytime you use ajax, you will only have the data returned to play with, in this case, you needed the button info replaced with the old button and the function applied to it again. Im glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think perhaps we should start by discussing the proper flow of your app. Assuming that your URL looks something like this `Products/product/10` and you intially load the page, your function runs providing you with right button and products as expected.. Lets say in this case product 10 does not exist in the session/cart so you see the ADD image button come up.. All good..  Now, when you click add, and from what you are saying, it adds the product to the session/cart, and you get a return JSON of ‘job:0’. So far it works as expected from the code I am seeing. A return of job:0 means that you ran the `setItem` function. Now the problem you are saying is that the view “is not changing asynchronously”. By this, do you mean that you expect the page to reload and run the function again so that the image can now say “remove”?

Comment: but you dont want the page to reload?

Comment: no why should i reload the page? i just want the image to change..is that possible?

Comment: you would reload the page so that the product controller runs again because at the moment the `myfunk` method just returns the JSON object.. nothing else. if you want to change the image then you would need to modify the `myfunk` method so that prior returning you any result, it also returns the status of the session so that you can decide hoe to change the image. I will try continuing helping you out with this maybe in 30 minutes from now.for now think of ways of separating your code so that you can re-use some parts for ajax.

Comment: i' am helpless i'll be waiting

Comment: i have managed to change the image onclick but now my page reloads..i've put the link to cart_c/myfunk in the anchor tag and changed the function to load views but that is not what i want..if by any chance soomeone can help that would be awsome